# How to Refresh ng-repeat using $.ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax

I am new in angularjs. I was trying to insert some reviews about a project. 
I am inserting the reviews using jquery ajax and bind all the reviews using angularjs on page load. My question is can I refresh or update the ng-repeated data immediate after the $.ajax success

This is my **jquery**

```
    $("#reviewSubmit").click(function () {
        var reviewData = JSON.stringify({ "Review": $('#txtReview').val() });
        document.cookie = "ScrollPosition=" + $(window).scrollTop();
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("MyReview", "ProductDetail")",
            data: reviewData,
            dataType: 'json',
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data == true) {
                    alert('Authorized');
                    $("#review_write").hide(250);
                    Test();
                }
                else {
                    var url = "@Url.Action("Login", "Login", new { area = ""})";
                    window.location = url;
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This is my **Angular js**

```
app.controller('ReviewModel', function ($scope, UserReviews) {
    getReviews();
    function getReviews() {
        UserReviews.getReviews().
        success(function (data) {
            $scope.Reviews = data;
            console.log($scope.Reviews);
        })
        .error(function (error) {
            $scope.status = 'Unable to load customer data: ' + error.message;
            console.log($scope.status);
        });
    }
})

app.factory('UserReviews', ['$http', function ($http) { 

    var UserReviews = {};

    UserReviews.getReviews = function () {
        var url = appurl + "/ProductDetail/GetUserReview";
        return $http.get(url);
    };

    return UserReviews;
    }]);
```

This is my **View**

```
                <div ng-app="myApp">
                    <div id="myElementWithController" ng-controller="ReviewModel">
                        <ul ng-repeat="item in Reviews">
                            <li>{{item.Comment}}</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Don't use $.ajax. Use $http service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've solved it. Inside the $.ajax success method I wrote the following line of code

```
var element = angular.element($('#MyElementWithController'));
element.scope().$apply();
```

It's immediately affected the DOM.

Answer (score 2):

Here because you are updating `scope` variable from `jQuery` method(out of angular context). Which doesn't run digest cycle & binding didn't get updated.

Use `$http.post` instead of `$.ajax` post will take care of digest cycle.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually kick a digest cycle to sync the view and model. You can do this by $apply, In success callback, do something

```
$scope.$apply();
```

One more thing, success and error are deprecated so use standard `then`

Comment: To be clear, the digest cycle only handles model -> view (which is what we want here).

Comment: can I use $scope.$apply(); inside the $.ajax method or inside angular js ? I tried to use inside the jquery then I get the error $scope.$apply is not a function

Comment: @LibinCJacob depends on where your jquery is located. Currently you have a click event binding, directly to an element, outside of the controller, so it can't access the controller's scope to cause a digest within it. Due to the way angular takes over the page, it's usually far easier to just drop jQuery and use angular if you are going to use angular at all.

Answer (score -1):

You can check if "**digest is already in progress or not**", if not you can forcefully run digest cycle.

```
if (!$scope.$$phase) {
    $scope.$apply();
    }
```

Your code will look like

```
 UserReviews.getReviews().then(
                        function(data) {
                                $scope.Reviews = data;
                                if (!$scope.$$phase) {
                                       $scope.$apply();
                                       }
                             }, 
                        function(error) {
                            console.log('error', error);
                        });
```